# b. Set up a recurrence relation for the number of multiplications made by this algorithm and solve it

Tags: algorithm, recurrence

T(n) = T(n/2) + 1, T(0) = T(1) = 1

I need help with an explanation how to arrive at the answer.

Comment: I am reading this is a textbook and its not clear at all.

Comment: just choose some random value `n` and replace it inside the equation, see what values you are getting observe them and go through the book again.Say for `n=0` you are getting `T(0)=T(0/2)+1` which is equal to `T(0)=1` similary replace for other cases.

Answer (score 0):

As per I understood, u r trying to find the order of the algo. If that's the case, have a look at below solution

[image]

Now for,

[image]

Hence the order of the algo is,

[image]